# TortoiseHG overlay icons too large for taste, any way to modify/edit them?

Tags: tortoisehg

I noticed in Tortoise **SVN** that there were various icon styles one could choose in the settings, such is not the case for TortoiseHG 2.6.1.

The icon overlays are obliterating too much at both small icon and large icon resolutions.

1) I poked around in the Tortoise install directory, peeking inside exe and dlls, but have not found any resources. But I did not inspect EVERY dll.

2) I am aware that the overlays can be turned off and on, this is unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here.
The icon files are located in C:\Program Files\Common Files\TortoiseOverlays\icons\XPStyle

Below is a link to modified icons that have been reduced in size by one third to alleviate the problem.

https://app.box.com/s/ow5ym4ucjpv92hq2zapg